# 'No module named flask', when I run through a URL

Tags: python, apache, flask

My files are placed as below in the apache shared hosting server -

```
/public_html/cgi-bin
 --- myenv (directory - virtual env)
 --- hello.cgi
 --- myapp.py
```

the `.htaccess` is in the root directory.

Now when I activate the virtual environment and run the `myapp.py` file  -

```
python myapp.py
```

this works fine. I get this -

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But now when I try to launch my page in the web browser, I get the below Import error in the logs (on the web page its 500 - Internal Server Error) -

```
 'No module named flask'
```

Please suggest if I need to give the path of the flask package anywhere in the `.cgi` or the `.py` file.

flask is installed in the `myenv` : `myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

`myapp.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello Ejaz"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`hello.cgi` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from myapp import app

os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = "www.mypage.com"
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = ""
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'
os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = ""

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer here - http://www.comfycoder.com/home/how_to_deploy_a_flask_app_in_apache_shared_hosting

updated my `hello.cgi` to this-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from myapp import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

and added these lines in `myapp.py` -

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the system python in the first line of your `cgi` file. Instead, point it to the python executable of your virtualenv.

Comment: I do not have python installed in my virtual env. I just have flask and sqlalchemy installed in  my virtual env. Should it still not work?